Scraping data from a website with infinite scrolling and dynamically loaded content using Python Selenium
I saw many topics if it comes to getting data from a website with infinite scrolling using selenium in python, but sadly i did not find any solution for my problem and i think i'm just missing something.
I am beginner if it comes to selenium.
I try to get top 500 movie titles from a Filmweb page and the main problem is i'm getting only 25 first titles. I execute scripts in while loop, but maybe in wrong place.
I tried using below code
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging']) 
browser = webdriver.Edge(options=options)

browser.get('https://www.filmweb.pl/ranking/film')

accept_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "didomi-notice-agree-button"))
)
accept_button.click()

browser.implicitly_wait(30)

items = []

last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(20)

    titles = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "rankingType__originalTitle")
    for i, title in enumerate(titles):
        movie_dict = {f"Movie Number : {i + 1}, 'Title': {title.text}"}
        items.append(movie_dict)

    new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

for movie_title in items:
    print(movie_title)

browser.quit()

The result i get:
{"Movie Number : 1, 'Title': The Shawshank Redemption 1994"}
{"Movie Number : 2, 'Title': Intouchables 2011"}
{"Movie Number : 3, 'Title': The Green Mile 1999"}
{"Movie Number : 4, 'Title': The Godfather 1972"}
{"Movie Number : 5, 'Title': 12 Angry Men 1957"}
{"Movie Number : 6, 'Title': 1994"}
{"Movie Number : 7, 'Title': One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest 1975"}
{"Movie Number : 8, 'Title': The Godfather: Part II 1974"}
{"Movie Number : 9, 'Title': The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King 2003"}
{"Movie Number : 10, 'Title': Schindler's List 1993"}
{"Movie Number : 11, 'Title': 1994"}
{"Movie Number : 12, 'Title': La vita è bella 1997"}
{"Movie Number : 13, 'Title': The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers 2002"}
{"Movie Number : 14, 'Title': Se7en 1995"}
{"Movie Number : 15, 'Title': Fight Club 1999"}
{"Movie Number : 16, 'Title': Goodfellas 1990"}
{"Movie Number : 17, 'Title': The Pianist 2002"}
{"Movie Number : 18, 'Title': 2019"}
{"Movie Number : 19, 'Title': Django Unchained 2012"}
{"Movie Number : 20, 'Title': A Beautiful Mind 2001"}
{"Movie Number : 21, 'Title': Inception 2010"}
{"Movie Number : 22, 'Title': The Silence of the Lambs 1991"}
{"Movie Number : 23, 'Title': The Lion King 1994"}
{"Movie Number : 24, 'Title': Scarface 1983"}
{"Movie Number : 25, 'Title': 2008"}

Some movie titles have only year, but thats because their original title is in another place in source code structure and i will deal with it later.
So firstly i wanna somehow extract 500 titles, then i will work with another data after i know how to deal with the current problem.
Maybe someone here had such problem and can help me.
Thanks in advance

Your main issue is you doesn't wait for Ads to be closed (it closing in 15 seconds automatically with no option to close it manually). So you scroll once to the bottom and new block can't be rendered because of Ad has not been closed yet.
After accepting cookies I suggest to add hardcoded wait (I don't see any option to get rid from that Ad) and then implement continuous scroll:

Get list of titles
Scroll to last title
Wait for last title position to be stable

There can be more complicated solutions like waiting for rendering for new elements to be rendered after scrolling and loop until new elements are stopped to be appearing, but for purpose of getting 500 movies this solution is enough.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
browser = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
action_chains = ActionChains(browser)

def wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(element):
    initial_location = element.location
    previous_location = initial_location
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < 1:
        current_location = element.location
        if current_location != previous_location:
            previous_location = current_location
            start_time = time.time()
        time.sleep(0.4)

def continuous_scroll(by, selector, times):
    for i in range(times):
        last_container = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((by, selector)))[-1]
        action_chains.move_to_element(last_container).perform()
        wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(last_container)

browser.get('https://www.filmweb.pl/ranking/film')
browser.maximize_window()

accept_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "didomi-notice-agree-button"))
)
accept_button.click()

# wait for ads to be closed automatically
time.sleep(20)
items = []

times = 20
selector = "rankingType__originalTitle"

continuous_scroll(By.CLASS_NAME, selector, times)
titles = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, selector)
for i, title in enumerate(titles):
    movie_dict = {f"Movie Number : {i + 1}, 'Title': {title.text}"}
    items.append(movie_dict)

for movie_title in items:
    print(movie_title)


Unless Selenium is needed for some other reasons, why not to pull the data directly from the server? Much simpler code, and depending on your network bandwidth, it might finish while you're still waiting for the ad to close.
import json
import re
import requests

url_list = 'https://www.filmweb.pl/ranking/film/'

req = requests.get(url_list)

# Parsing top movies to a list
film_list = re.search('(?<=keys:").+?(?=".split)', req.text).group(0).split(' ')
film_list = [x.split('_')[1] for x in film_list]

# Get the necessary data
url_data = 'https://www.filmweb.pl/api/v1/title/%s/info'
headers = {'x-locale': 'pl'}

data_film = []
for film in film_list:
    req = requests.get(url_data % film, headers=headers)
    response = json.loads(req.text)
    data_film.append(response)

Output would look like this
[{'title': 'Skazani na Shawshank', 'originalTitle': 'The Shawshank Redemption', 'year': 1994, 'type': 'film', 'subType': 'film_cinema', 'posterPath': '/10/48/1048/6925401_1.$.jpg'}, 
 {'title': 'Nietykalni', 'originalTitle': 'Intouchables', 'year': 2011, 'type': 'film', 'subType': 'film_cinema', 'posterPath': '/33/90/583390/7441162.$.jpg'}, 
 {'title': 'Zielona mila', 'originalTitle': 'The Green Mile', 'year': 1999, 'type': 'film', 'subType': 'film_cinema', 'posterPath': '/08/62/862/7517878_1.$.jpg'}]
 ...
 ...

It's also easy to expand the query by using other databases or adding  filters. Just replace the url_list or url_data with these links:
# If filtering is needed, any combination of Country, Genre and Year is possible
# This link is an example of filtering. Country - USA, Genre - Animation, Year - 2020.
# url_list = 'https://www.filmweb.pl/ranking/film/country/53/genre/2/2020'

# Other databases
# url_data = 'https://www.filmweb.pl/api/v1/film/%s/description'
# url_data = 'https://www.filmweb.pl/api/v1/vod/film/%s/providers/list'
# url_data = 'https://www.filmweb.pl/api/v1/film/%s/dates'
# url_data = 'https://www.filmweb.pl/api/v1/film/%s/rankings'
# url_data = 'https://www.filmweb.pl/api/v1/film/%s/titles'


that is cool too, but i am not sure if i understand how regexp works here, could you add explaining ? thanks
